# where to install latest version of Libertinus from git?

Tags: fonts, installing, texmf-local, libertinus

I want to install the latest version of the Libertinus Fonts from https://github.com/khaledhosny/libertinus into my local tex-tree (macOS)(/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/). Therefore, I downloaded the whole git folder and there are the .otf files and two additional folders (sources and tools). Do I need the two folders or do I just need the .otf files?

If I need the folders, where should I put them? There is no real guide or at least I wasn't able to find one.

Tanks!

Comment: If you only need these fonts for one document you can install the OTF files in the same folder as your document.  Otherwise the system font directory will also do fine.

Comment: and what are the additional folders for? I would prefer to keep the fonts out of my system font-library because I only use it with LaTeX.

Comment: The other folders you only need when you want to contribute to the development of the font or want to compile the OTF files yourself from source.  I don't see why you don't want to put the fonts in the system fonts folder, but if you insist, put them in `texmf-local/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus` (you might have to generate some of those folders).

Comment: I have one additional question: How do I know if LaTeX uses the font version "installed" by me under `/texmf-local/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus` or the standard version, which is included in TeXLive under `texlive/2017/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus` ?