# Install an Updated Version of an Open Type Font for the Use with LuaLaTeX in TeX Live 2018

Tags: fonts, luatex, fontspec, opentype, texlive-2018

In my TeX Live 2018 installation on Linux, I want to replace the *Libertinus* fonts shipped with TeX Live by their latest GitHub build. If they are used in LuaLaTeX e.g. via

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}
```

the new version should be used automatically. It seems (thanks to Thérèse) that in older versions of TeX Live it was sufficient to place them in a system font folder like `~/.fonts/`. This does no longer work in TeX Live 2018. Also the local tree `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local/fonts/` does not work.

Please also include other steps required like running commands to update font caches and such.

It is not important to me, if the old versions are stil installed or deleted, I just don't want to use them anymore.

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: @TeXnician I am using Linux. (Manjaro)

Comment: have you run an update on the FNDB?

Comment: @naphaneal No, could you explain what that means?

Comment: it means you have to update the Font Name Database. basically, from the CLI run commands to update the FNDB and remap the fonts to TXL. see instructions on: https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html

Comment: @naphaneal I dont't fully undertand the page. Can I simply deleted the old otf files, replace them by the new ones and then follow the instructions from the page? How do I find out `newfont.map` in Step 4?

Comment: Don't delete the files from TeX Live. If you do, you'll only confuse things and the change won't last anyway. How did you install TeX Live? What's the content of `/etc/fonts/conf.avail/09-texlive-fonts.conf`?

Comment: Note that the latest versions will not necessarily work as well with Lua/XeTeX as the versions shipped in TeX Live, because TeX Live provides a support package designed around the fonts it includes. It may all be hunky-dory, but just watch things in case is less hunky or, even, less dory.

Comment: Don’t worry about not understanding https://www.tug.org/fonts/fontinstall.html, because it’s not for OpenType fonts used with `fontspec`. Your question is more or less the same as that at https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/421943, but neither has an adequate answer yet. It used to be that fonts installed in `~/.fonts/` would be used before those in texlive, but that seems not to be true in TeX Live 2018 — which is problematic for those who put newer or repaired versions of fonts in `~/.fonts/`.

Comment: @cfr Thank you very much for your help. I am afraid that file does not exist. There are lots of config files in that directory but none with either `09` or `texlive` in its name. I installed TL through downloading the official TUG installer file for unix.

Comment: @Thérèse Thank you very much for your help. You are right that the other question is very similar. I myself also asked https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/431233/where-to-save-updated-version-of-a-tex-live-font before. Since I could not solve my problem based on the comments there, I thought I would go after the side comment *(but I would replace the original probably too ...)* by Ulrike Fischer. I also observed the behaviour that TL would not use the fonts from ~/.fonts/ as you describe it.

Comment: The easiest way is to write `\setmainfont{Libertinus Serif}[Path = <Path to your file>]`.

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Unfortunately, what you suggest won’t work: when specifying the path, you must also use the filename of the font. That’s not inconvenient for a single, decorative face, but for a large type family rich in features, especially for one with optical sizes, it’s a lot of work that wasn’t necessary until 2018.

Comment: @Thérèse you mean that `\setmainfont{LibertinusSerif.otf}[Path = ...]` won't automatically detect which font to use for bold and italic faces?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Right. See the last line on p. 10 of the fontspec documentation.

Comment: @Thérèse what happened in 2018 update?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman That’s what I’d like to know. This change in behavior seems not to have been announced in any of the documentation.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78324/discussion-between-michael-fraiman-and-therese).

Comment: If you don't have that file, `fontconfig` can't use TeX Live fonts anyway.

Comment: Try the following: put the font folder in either `/usr/share/fonts/opentype` or `/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype`. Open TeX Live manager using `sudo tlmgr gui`. Select `Actions->Handle symlinks in system dirs`, then select `Update symbolic links`. Next, select `Actions->Update font map database`.

Comment: @Khue Er ... what would that do? Updating the font map database combines `.map` file fragments - it has nothing to do with this. And droppint them into either of those directories is a bad idea. One is managed by `tlmgr` and the other by the distro's package manager.

Comment: Have you tried installing the fonts into `TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/opentype`? You'd need to `mktexlsr` if you did this, I think. I don't know if this would work, mind, but it might be worth trying. You might also try `TEXMFHOME/fonts/opentype`, but I'm very leery of installing any fonts into the personal tree, even though the usual considerations don't apply here. (If you try TEXMFHOME, no need to run `mktexlsr`.) I think it would be worth editing this question to make it LuaTeX specific since we think it is engine-specific. And maybe put that into the subject of the question.

Comment: @Thérèse How sure are you that it is the 2018 update which did this? What I mean is, if you had an existing font cache, could the change have happened during the 2017 cycle, but not affected you because you were just using the existing cache?

Comment: @cfr I run `fc-cache -frvv` and `luaotfload-tool --update` *very* often, and even more so in April and May of this year, because there were some new fonts I just couldn’t resist, as well as updated versions of fonts I already had.  I’m talking about renewing the cache several times weekly.

Comment: @cfr Hmmm.  Have just been reading the man page for luaotfload-tool, and tried to look at the current configuration by running `luaotfload-tool --dumpconf > luaotfload.conf` as it suggests.  Result: `...-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-configuration.lua:655: bad argument #3 to 'stringformat' (not a number in proper range)`  I haven’t edited the configuration.

Comment: @Thérèse Did you have while running `fc-cache --force --verbose` some error/report like
`fc-cache: "E:/#WINDOWSFONTDIR#": skipping, no such directory`?
I have such message since TeXLive 2018. May this be some problem with font caching in TeXLive 2018?

Comment: @Leonid No, everything looked normal.

Comment: @cfr I’m not sure but I thought this is similar to my question here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/434032/24048. The above steps are how I solved my problem, so I thought they would help. Sorry if it’s not related.

Comment: @Khue Whatever helped you, it wasn't updating the map files.

Comment: @Leonid Looks very odd unless you're using Windows.

Comment: @Thérèse I don't get that error. I get `luaotfload-dump.conf` created (because that's the file name I redirected to). Exit `0`.

Comment: @cfr Windows, but it is not what caused problems. graphwiz's 2.38 fc-cache was in PATH with more priority. PATH sorting helped. But i still get `C:\texlive\2018\bin\win32\runscript.tlu:811: ...-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-configuration.lua:655: bad argument #3 to 'stringformat' (not a number in proper range)` inside `luaotfload.conf` after `luaotfload-tool --dumpconf > luaotfload.conf` same as @Thérèse

Answer (score 4):

`luaotfload` uses a two level lookup when given a font name like `Libertinus Serif`:
First the name is looked up in the cache to get the filename, in this case `libertinusserif-regular.otf`, then a separate lookup is used to locate this file.
While the name lookup preferes files in the system directory, the filename lookup finds the font in the TeX tree.

To avoid this you have to avoid using the same filenmae for the font.
For example you can add the version number of Libertinus to the filenames while copying them into `~/.fonts`. Then just run `luaotfload-tool -uf` for `luaotfload` to pick up the changes. You do not have to run `fc-cache` or other fontconfig commands, `luaotfload` does not use `fontconfig`, it just reads the same configuration files.

Another solution would be to patch `luaotfload`. If the file `luaotfload-database.lua` is patched with

```
diff --git a/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua b/luaotfload-database.lua
index 9c8c298..ca1fca6 100644
--- a/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/luatex/luaotfload/luaotfload-database.lua
+++ b/luaotfload-database.lua
@@ -721,9 +721,9 @@ local get_font_file = function (index)
             return true, basename, entry.subfont
         end
     else --- system, local
-        local fullname = name_index.files.full [index]
+        local fullname = entry.fullpath
         if lfsisfile (fullname) then
-            return true, basename, entry.subfont
+            return true, fullname, entry.subfont
         end
     end
     return false
@@ -1024,7 +1024,7 @@ local lookup_fontname = function (specification, name, style)
             or face.fullname   == name
             or face.psname     == name
         then
-            return face.basename, face.subfont
+            return face.fullpath, face.subfont
         elseif face.familyname == name then
             if typographicsubfamily == style
                 or subfamily == style
@@ -1043,10 +1043,10 @@ local lookup_fontname = function (specification, name, style)
         end
     end
     if fallback then
-        return fallback.basename, fallback.subfont
+        return fallback.fullpath, fallback.subfont
     end
     if lastresort then
-        return lastresort.basename, lastresort.subfont
+        return lastresort.fullpath, lastresort.subfont
     end
     return nil, nil
 end
```

the actual paths from the name cache are used directly and this fixes the problem. I haven't tested this a lot so it might have other consequences.

Comment: Works fine. I will maybe wait for the other participants to confirm that it works for them aswell and then accept and award you the bounty.

Comment: Unless I’ve misunderstood something, this seems to require loading the newly named font by filename, and then specifying its italic, etc., also by filename — a complexity that wasn’t necessary until 2018.  Is that the case?

Comment: @Thérèse No. You can load the font by the fontname, but the underlying file still needs a distinct filename.

Comment: That’s what I had hoped, but my test didn’t work.

Comment: @Thérèse Let us [continue this in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78389/visibility-of-overwritten-opentype-fonts-in-texlive2018)

Comment: Thanks for your help; this works now that I’ve removed `export OSFONTDIR="$HOME/.fonts"` from my `.bashrc`, logged out and in again, and regenerated the luaotfload cache.

Comment: This is not a good solution. What if I want to use files in `/usr/share/fonts` in preference to those in TL? There is then no way to achieve this because the order is not configurable and I can't just rename files installed by my distro's package manager. Even if that was an OK thing to do, it would be undone every time the font package is updated. This will work for @Thérèse, where the concern is with a personal fonts directory, but it is no good for the standard case.

Comment: @Thérèse It is just bonkers that the name lookup goes one way, the file lookup the other and that none of it is, apparently, customisable. Moreover, the fact that it uses fontconfig configuration, but in a way that ignores significant parts of it is nuts. Really pleased I've stuck to pdfLaTeX!

Comment: @cfr Bonkers that the change wasn’t announced either; I wonder whether it was unintended and may be undone soon?

Comment: If you load the font using the font name, how can you tell LuaTeX to use a specific file name? Is it just that, if the names are different, the system/home one will be preferred, whereas if the names are the same, the TL one will be preferred? (Because of the interaction between the name vs file lookups.) Surely it can't be meant to work like this?

Comment: @Thérèse I can't believe it is intended. It is altogether too weird. But, then, I've thought that about changes to software before. Has anybody reported the ... er ... oddities?

Comment: @cfr I don’t see a report at https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues — but maybe a report will emerge from this question once it’s been tidied up.

Comment: @Thérèse Please feel free to link to this question when reporting unwanted behaviour. I don't quite understand all the technical details so perhaps I won't take this step myself.

Comment: @cfr I added a patch which would prefer fonts in the system font directories without renaming. After the change even `set_location_preference` is respected...

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Aha. That sounds good. So it is configurable?

Comment: @cfr This depends. You cannot set it in `luaotfload.conf` and lookups are cached, so the configuartion would have to be in every source file you compile, but then it would be configurable. It would be quite easy to expose to `luaotfload.conf` through.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger Exposing it sounds helpful, if that's easy to do. Not just because it would make it configurable more easily, but because it would also make it more transparent. Setting it in every source file doesn't sound like a great option, although being able to override a default on a per-flle basis is certainly good. It would be helpful to have some comments somewhere in `texmf.cnf` and/or `luaotfload.conf` since those are reasonably obvious places to look.

Comment: https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/422

Answer (score 4):

When I (on windows) have a font in more than one locations, all locations are in the `luaotfload-names.lua`. I have some doubts (but testing is not easy) that the order in which this font locations are used is well defined (tables in `lua` don't have a well defined order).

So I would avoid to have more than one copy of a font in accessible locations.

This means for a font coming via texlive that I would either

- deinstall the original font package
- or blacklist the original fonts in a (local) `luaotfload-blacklist.cnf`

For the second variant:

- Add e.g.

  ```
   d:/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/libertinus/libertinusserif-regular.otf
  ```

  to a `luaotfload-blacklist.cnf` e.g. in `texmf-local/tex/luatex/luaotfload`
- Delete the luaotfload-names.lua.gz and luc
- Delete also the lua and/luc-files from the font in `\texlive\2018\texmf-var\luatex-cache\generic\fonts\otl` (they contain pathes too)
- Recreate the database with `luaotfload-tool -uf`.

This imho should blacklist the font. Imho it is sadly not possible to blacklist complete directories.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger on Windows the ["local"] and the ["system"] fields are empty on this pc. All entries are in the texmf field.   And the keys are unique, but e.g. `ibmplexsans.r` maps to an index number which is one of the clones I placed in various locations but it is quite unclear why this index number was choosen.